# Iframe widget google analytics bounce rate

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, widget

I have an iframe widget that I embed on sites with a GA tracking code (a new code for each site the widget is embedded on).  We are seeing bounce rates of 55%, but our widget is a 1 page site so I would have thought the bounce rate would have been 100%.  I track a number of things that happen in our widget using custom events and I am not seeing huge numbers of interaction, yet the bounce rate is still low.

What events (there are no refreshes of the box, everything is done behind the scenes via asynch requests) could Google be seeing that make the bounce rate not be 100%?

(yes I read Google Analytics Bounce Rate Under 100% on a Single Page Site, it doesn't really answer my question)

Answer (score 0):

`_trackEvent()` has an optional parameter `opt_noninteraction` -- from the [Event Tracking docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking#_gat.GA_EventTracker_._trackEvent):

> By default, the event hit sent by _trackEvent() will impact a visitor's bounce rate. By setting this parameter to true, this event hit will not be used in bounce rate calculations.

Sounds like this could account for some portion of your bounce rate.